# Where to place the clickListeners in my code?

Tags: android

The app has initial message screen that is displayed the first time it run where a date is obtained from user using datepicker then from next time it goes directly to main.xml. This is the logic i tried
in onCreate()

```
if(<date set>)
{
   <open main.xml>
   <listeners> 
}
else
{
  <get date from user>
  <set flag>
  setContentView(R.layout.initial_msg);
  <make changes in main.xml according to date> 
}
```

The problem is the first time it executes it obtains the date but the listeners are not loaded, i think this is because the code is not executed at all. when i place the listener outside the if block i get a null pointer exception. But when i close the app and start it again it works as this time it opens if() block not else().

```
 public class pgactivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar tempDate;
    TextView tv1,tv2;
    Menu theMenu;
    LayoutInflater li;
    int week;

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    //@override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth)
    {
        c.set(Calendar.DATE,dayOfMonth);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        if(checkValidity())
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
            //set the flag that indicates concieved_date has been added
            editor.putBoolean("concieved_date", true); 

            int datepref;  
            datepref=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
            datepref=datepref*1000000;
            datepref+=c.get(Calendar.MONTH)*10000;
            datepref+=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            editor.putInt("date",datepref);
            editor.commit();
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            setData();
        }
    }
};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //check if concieved date is set from the prefs file "app_data"
    //if yes open application page else open initial message screen to set the date
    prefs=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("app_data",Context.MODE_APPEND);

    if(prefs.getBoolean("concieved_date", false))
    {

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setData();

        //Listener for the temp button 'false'
        //It resets the flag used to indicate if date is set or not. used for testing purpose
        Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setfalse);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {               
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("concieved_date", false);
                editor.commit();

                TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
                tv3.setText("entered listener");
            }
    });

        //Listener for the weekly_tip text view
        //when clicked open the layout giving the full description
        TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.weekly_tip);
        tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent j=new Intent(pgactivity.this,weekly.class);
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putInt("cur_week",week);
                j.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(j);
            }
        });

        //Listener for open_remainders button to switch to Remainders page
        Button btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.open_remainders);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(pgactivity.this,RemaindersPage.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.initial_msg);

        //click listener for textview 2
        TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.init_msg);
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("concieved_date", true);
                editor.commit();

                new DatePickerDialog(pgactivity.this,d,
                        c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
    }

}

void setData()
{
    Long sec,tempSec;
    int date,day,month,year;
    date=prefs.getInt("date", 10101010);
    day=date/1000000;
    date=date%1000000;
    month=date/10000;
    date=date%10000;
    year=date;
    c.set(year, month, day);
    tempDate=c;

    //insert value to concieved_date textfield
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.concieved_date);
    tv1.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd MMM yyyy", tempDate));

    //insert value to delivery_date
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.delivery_date);
    tempDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 280);
    tv1.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd MMM yyyy", tempDate));

    //insert value to days_to_delivery
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.days_to_delivery);
    c=Calendar.getInstance();  //c has current date
    sec=tempDate.getTimeInMillis()-c.getTimeInMillis();  //find diff in millisecs
    sec=sec/86400000;
    tv1.setText(sec.toString());

    //insert value for days_into_pregnancy
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.days_into_pregnancy);
    tempSec=280-sec;
    tv1.setText(tempSec.toString());

    //insert value for current_week
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_week);
    tempSec=tempSec/7;
    week=tempSec.intValue();
    tv1.setText(tempSec.toString());
}

//user method to check the date validity : check if date entered is a reasonable value
boolean checkValidity()
{
    Long duration;
    tempDate=Calendar.getInstance(); //get today's date in c

    //check if user date is on or before today's date
    if(tempDate.before(c)) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setMessage("Specified date should be on or before today's date");
        ad.setNeutralButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,int arg1){}
                }
        );
        ad.show();
        return false;
    }
    //check if diff between user date and todays date is more than 280 days
    duration=tempDate.getTimeInMillis()-c.getTimeInMillis();
    duration/=86400000;
    if(duration>280)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setMessage("Specified date can be atmost 280 days before today's date");
        ad.setNeutralButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,int arg1){}
                }
        ).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

}

Comment: set the listeners AFTER the if-else block, not before, then you will avoid the nullpointerexception

Comment: You may think you're making it easier by showing us pseudocode instead of actual code, but that only helps if the error is in your logic and not your implementation. If you want help with errors in your implementation, show your actual code.

Comment: I was out for a period, i have added the full code of the main class pgactivity.class

Answer (score 1):

If you need your listeners in the `else`-block, too, you can put this code before the `if`-block.

If the layout changes if the `if` or the `else` is executed, you can use the [`onClick`-attribute in your XML-Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) definition.

To save your data, you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: i dont need the listener in the else block as they each load a diff screen. I cant place the listeners outside as main.xml is not opened yet and all the listeners are for buttons in main.xml

Comment: @user699617 - Yes you can place them outside the if-else block, but they need to be set AFTER the if-else block, when your content view has been set.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth that doesn't work either as i call a separate activity to open the initial one time message the program continues to execute in the first activity so error occurs.